# Magento Cart_Product.Add Custom Options File Upload via Soap API

Tags: php, magento, soap

Can not achieve to upload a file via soap api to Cart. I want user to add a product to cart with a required custom option which is an image.

So spent hours, can not find any resource/documentation/same problem anywhere but actually figure out, soap api requires array (ok, but what are the parameters?) And It does not throw any error if something goes wrong (weird?)

So in practice what I am willing to achieve:

```
// Prepare image
$newImage = array(
    'file' => array(
        'name' => $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'],
        'content' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'])),
        'mime'    => 'image/png'
        ),
    'label'    => $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']
);

// Prepare product & Custom options
$arrProducts = array(
    array(
        'product_id'     => '7',
        'qty'             => 1,
        'options'        => array ( '30' => $newImage ) // optionId_1 => optionValue_1
    )
);

// lets do adding
$resultCartProductAdd = $client->call(
    $session,
    'cart_product.add',
    array(
        $quoteId,
        $arrProducts
    )
);
```

The problem is, the image is not uploaded to /media/custom_options/quote folder where should belongs to and when order complete can not see anywhere. As I mentioned, there is no error thrown while this process..

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Did you found any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this....

```
 $arrProducts = array(
        array(
            'product_id'     => '7',
            'qty'             => 1,
            'options'        => array ( 'options_30_file' => $newImage,'options_30_file_action'=>'save_new' ) 
        )
    );
```

or

```
 $arrProducts = array(
            array(
                'product_id'     => '7',
                'qty'             => 1,
               'options_30_file' => $newImage,
              'options_30_file_action'=>'save_new'  
            )
        );
```

Let me if any issue

Comment: thx Amit for your reply but both approach throw this error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [1022] Please specify the product's required option(s).

Comment: btw, magento ver. 1.8.0